# Not able to Put TextView Under Google Vision Scanner View in Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I want to display a text view under the scanner view using Java at the same time, but it seems doesn't work. When I run the app, only the scanner view that displayed. But when I pressed back, this text view appear. How come this happened?
This is my code:

```
public class BarCodeM extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String key = "";
    private boolean autoFocus = false;
    private boolean useFlash = false;
    private BarcodeReaderFragment mBarcodeReaderFragment;

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_bar_code_m);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


        FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragmentById = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fm_container);
        if (fragmentById != null) {
            fragmentTransaction.remove(fragmentById);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        launchBarCodeActivity();

        LinearLayout layout2 = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView titleView = new TextView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        titleView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        titleView.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge);
        titleView.setText("Hallo!");
        layout2.addView(titleView);

        setContentView(layout);

        //Intent launchIntent = BarcodeReaderActivity.getLaunchIntent(this, key,true, false);
        //startActivityForResult(launchIntent, 1098);

    }

    private void launchBarCodeActivity() {
        Intent launchIntent = BarcodeReaderActivity.getLaunchIntent(this, key,true, false);
        startActivityForResult(launchIntent, 1098);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "error in  scanning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if (requestCode == 1098 && data != null) {
            Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra(BarcodeReaderActivity.KEY_CAPTURED_BARCODE);
            Toast.makeText(this, barcode.rawValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

frame layout design:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fm_container"
        android:layout_width="480dp"
        android:layout_height="480dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How do I put this text view under the scanner properly ?

Comment: As per code u created `layout2` but u never added it to root .

Comment: you can try one thing - make your parent layout Relative layout and inside this use your frame layout and a textview, set textview parent bottom - true then set frame layout above textview. please do let me know it it is working or not

Answer (score 0):

you are setting `LinearLayout layout` in `setContentView` so posted XML is irrelevant, it isn't inflated by `Activity` at all. and your ``LinearLayout layout2`have added`TextView`, but itself it isn't added anywhere, just created in memory with` Activity`s context and left there

at first use `setContentView(R.id.activity_layout);` (`activity_bar_code_m`?). put your `TextView` below fragment frame in XML or get reference to root `LinearLayout` and add `new TextView` to it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root_of_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fm_container"
        android:layout_width="480dp"
        android:layout_height="480dp" />

    <!-- fixed TextView -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/some_text"
        android:layout_width="480dp"
        android:layout_height="480dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

dynamic way

```
TextView titleView = new TextView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
titleView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
titleView.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge);
titleView.setText("Hallo!");

LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout ) findViewById(R.id.root_of_layout);
rootView .addView(titleView);
```

Comment: I have tried it, but still same like before which is the text view appear after scanning done.. and it's appears on the top of layout

Comment: in currently posted code you are calling `launchBarCodeActivity` - if this is your "scanning" screen then you cant modify it as this is separated `Activity` styled and handled by 3rd party lib, this isn't your layout. so you can't add anything there. this is the reason why your text shows after scan complete or back button press - you are exiting this scanning `Activity` and getting back to your layout, which may contain whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved by change the whole code like this:

```
   LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(this);
   parent.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

   View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_barcode_reader, null);
   FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.fm_container);
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(420,510);
   frameLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

   TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   lparams.setMargins(10,20,20,40);
   tv1.setLayoutParams(lparams);
   tv1.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge);
   tv1.setText("Hallo!");

   parent.addView(frameLayout);
   parent.addView(tv1);

   setContentView(parent);

   addBarcodeReaderFragment();
```

**addBarcodeReaderFragment() method:**

```
private void addBarcodeReaderFragment() {
    BarcodeReaderFragment readerFragment = BarcodeReaderFragment.newInstance(true, false, View.VISIBLE);
    readerFragment.setListener(this);
    FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fm_container, readerFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```